Could not open input file: artisan in Terminal cPanel
I put my Laravel application online via cPanel and when I try to execute a command in the cPanel Terminal I get this error:
Could not open input file: artisan

Any ideas ?

This usually happens if you are executing the command outside of the Laravel project. Confirm that you are inside the root directory of the Laravel project then execute the command. You can do this by running the following command:
cd /path/to/my-project

Alternatively, list the files inside the directory that you are executing the command from and see if the artisan file is present. You can use the following command to list the files inside your project.
ls -l

So long as the artisan file is present in this directory, then you should not see the error.
